# How to open multiple URLs in each function?

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

I've this code for get all links and open it in new tabs.

```
    var OptionBarSelector = "div.tCenter";
    var button = "<input id='allTabs' type='button' class='bold' style='width: 140px;'value='open all in new tab'/>";
    var host = "http://rutracker.org/forum";
    var tableId = "tor-tbl";
    var rowHref = ".tCenter.hl-tr td.row4.t-title a";  
$(function(){

    console.log("Rutracker search results in All Tab loaded");
    $(OptionBarSelector).append(button);  

    $("#allTabs").on('click',function(){

      $("#"+tableId+" tr"+rowHref).each(function(index,item){
          var link = host + $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
          window.open(link,"_newTab");     
    });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<td class="row4 med tLeft t-title" style="max-width: 669px;">
        <div class="wbr t-title" style="max-width: 669px;">
                        <a data-topic_id="534143" class="med tLink hl-tags bold" href="./viewtopic.php?t=534143">Text<span class="brackets-pair">[2001-2013, PDF, RUS]</span>Text 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tg-534143" class="t-tags"><span class="tg">Journal</span></div>
    </td>
```

But is opened only first link. How to fix it ?
And I want to keep current tab is active.

**UPDATE**
I changed code, but now this code open only first link in new tab and the other in popup window. How to open the other links in new tabs instead of popup window?

```
    var OptionBarSelector = "div.tCenter";
    var button = "<input target='_blank' id='allTabs' type='button' class='bold' style='width: 140px;'value='open all in new tab'/>";
    var host = "http://rutracker.org/forum";
    var tableId = "tor-tbl";
    var rowHref = ".tCenter.hl-tr td.row4.t-title a";  
$(function(){
    $(OptionBarSelector).append(button);

    var allLinks = new Array();
       $("#"+tableId+" tr"+rowHref).each(function(index,item){
          var link = host + $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
          allLinks.push(link);
    });
    var varAllOpen = "";    
    for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++)
    {
        varAllOpen += "window.open('"+allLinks[i]+"','"+i+"');";
    }   
    console.log(varAllOpen);
    $("#allTabs").attr("onclick",varAllOpen);
    console.log("Rutracker search results in All Tab loaded");
});
```

Comment: Please paste your html code too

Comment: I write script for tampermonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fair bit of questionable JS in your code, but the main problem is that you're building a string, then executing it as if it's a function. Don't solve problems that don't exist: if you want a function to trigger on a click, bind a function, to the click event:

```
$(function(){
  $(OptionBarSelector).append(button);

  var links = [];      // don't use new Array()

  $("#"+tableId+" tr"+rowHref).each(function() {
    links.push(host + this.href.substring(1));
  });

  // actually bind a click handler function,
  // don't use strings attributes
  $("#allTabs").click(function() {
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      window.open(link);
    });
  });
});
```